# Expression Blend very sluggish with >1000 items

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

I've gone a bit crazy with a piece of XAML and have a lot of small shapes.

The designer has gone really sluggish - I was flicking through the options hoping for a 'don't re-render objects that have not changed' flag or similar to give me back a bit more control.

Couldn't find anything, but thought it was worth a post on here.  Does anyone know of a way of speeding things up?

Thanks

Comment: Stop using slow markup technologies for high detail designs? :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, could this instance be an example of a design that could be consolidated into less shapes? For example I worked with a developer recently that had drawn over 200 rectangles to make grid lines that I condensed into like 20 that I just spanned the columns/rows with instead of trying to put one in each individual cell as he had it and it improved 100%, or perhaps you could substitute the shapes with actual images?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion - but no, it's quite intricate and not just squares.

Comment: Use a geometry group on a drawing brush instead. You can generate many paths with different colors, and it draws to one object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the various options in Blend to combine multiple paths/shapes into a single path.  This will improve both your design time and run time performance.